# Which format is appropriate to store a float value in AWS dynamodb table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to store a float value (example: 10.12) in AWS dynamo db table.

The options available are:

[image]

To hold float value, should I choose string or number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Long pending issue but DynamoDB apparently does not support float straight out-of-the-box.

That said, storing it as `string` is the consensus work-around.

For reference, please refer to this answer from the official AWS Boto3 GitHub page, [here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/665#issuecomment-340260257).

> What worked for us is wrapping the floating point value into str and casting to Decimal, no loss of precision!